# Oracle Parameterized query in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0, ado.net, sql-injection

```
string sqlCmd = @"SELECT r.row_id AS resp_id,
                         r.name AS resp_name
                  FROM srb.s_resp r,
                       srb.s_per_resp pr,
                       srb.s_contact c,
                       srb.s_user u
                  WHERE r.row_id = pr.resp_id
                    AND u.row_id = c.row_id
                    AND c.person_uid = pr.per_id
                    AND UPPER(u.login) = @login
                 ORDER BY r.name";

OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(getConnectionString(username, password));
OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();

conSiebel.Open();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Connection = con;
command.CommandText = sqlCmd;

command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("login", username));

IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
reader.Close();
```

I am trying to add the `@login` parameter to the above query but it was not adding, Can anyone help me to fix this ?

Comment: First thing I saw is that the new login parameter is never assigned a `ParameterDirection`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a colon instead (`:login`).

```
 string sqlCmd = @"SELECT  r.row_id AS resp_id,
                                    r.name AS resp_name
                            FROM    srb.s_resp r,
                                    srb.s_per_resp pr,
                                    srb.s_contact c,
                                    srb.s_user u
                            WHERE   r.row_id = pr.resp_id
                                    AND u.row_id = c.row_id
                                    AND c.person_uid = pr.per_id
                                    AND UPPER(u.login) = :login
                                    ORDER BY r.name";
```