# How do I display a select from database consisting of multiple join in a text box?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have to do a select from database that have multiple join( i will show you belong) and i put in one   command . The problem it is next one : a select something from a table and when i run the code it tell me something like that : " Column '....' does not belong to table ." and i look into table and it is. I will put code for take a look. Do you have any idea? I am sure i do something wrong but i don t know what.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=..." +
                          "User=..." +
                          "Password=..";

OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

con.Open();
string select3 = "SELECT tblOwner.OwnerFirstName , tblOwner.OwnerLastName, tblOwner.OwnerEmailID, tblOwner.OwnerLoc, tblDomain.DomainName " +
                 " FROM tblDomain " +
                 "  INNER JOIN(tblOwner INNER JOIN tblProductInfo ON tblOwner.OwnerID = tblProductInfo.OwnerID) ON tblDomain.DomainIDShort = tblOwner.DomainID" +
                 "  WHERE(((tblProductInfo.Productname) = ' "+ mystring + 
                 "'" + "))";

OracleDataAdapter aa = new OracleDataAdapter(select3, con);
DataTable cc = new DataTable();
bb.Fill(cc);

foreach (DataRow ww in dt.Rows)
{
    textBox2.Text = (ww["DomainName"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Please add the full exception message and describe how you checked that the column exists.

Comment: I think there is also too many SPACE's in Your select string, T_SQL is sensitive on this.

Comment: Please be very careful that the way you're defining your query is very prone to malicious attacks, especially if "mystring" relies on user input. Better used a parametrized query, as for example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811897/oracle-parameterized-query-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The code you post doesn't make much sense. Where does `bb` from? Why it isn't `aa.Fill(cc)`?  Why it is `dt.Rows` instead of `cc.Rows`? Is this even your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Your DataTable seems to not have a column called "DomainName". You can use the following code to list the existing column names in the output window of visual studio.

```
foreach (DataColumn col in cc.Columns)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(col.ColumnName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: You are filling `DataTable` from different data adapter.

```
OracleDataAdapter aa = new OracleDataAdapter(select3, con); // aa created
DataTable cc = new DataTable();
bb.Fill(cc);  // 'bb' fills data
```

Second: You are reading data from different `DataTable`, not that which you are filling with data.

```
DataTable cc = new DataTable();
bb.Fill(cc);  // 'cc' variable filled with data

foreach (DataRow ww in dt.Rows) // reading rows from 'dt' variable
{
    textBox2.Text = (ww["DomainName"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: i put there cc.Rows and doesn't work, tell me same erros(column name does not exist)

Comment: `cc`still will be filled with something different than you expect, because you are filling with wrong adapter

Comment: how should I do it?