# Run a sql query from PS, and loop in criteria in the where clause

Tags: arrays, powershell, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have code where I'm creating an index file by parsing out pieces of a file name.

This file name:
25643245_AjaWar_Prav_2_FT_20200701.pdf

Will create this line in the index file:
256432245|ST|W-HIGH SCHOOL TRANSCRIPT|@@TEST-LOCATION\25643245_AjaWar_Prav_2_FT_20200701.pdf

The problem is that the first parse of '256432245' isn't a primary key in our database, so I have to convert to a primary key, then store the primary key into the index file in place of '256432245'

I have part of the query that builds the index file working correctly, but not the part that queries and returns the converted ID. If I run only the part of the query that returns just one ID, that also works. I'm having a problem getting the query to work within the "foreach".

I currently get this a result:

|ST|W-HIGH SCHOOL TRANSCRIPT|@@TEST-LOCATION\25643245_AjaWar_Prav_2_FT_20200701.pdf

When I want to get:

8992004|ST|W-HIGH SCHOOL TRANSCRIPT|@@TEST-LOCATION\25643245_AjaWar_Prav_2_FT_20200701.pdf

Where '8992004' is the SPRIDEN_ID is the result of the sql query.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
foreach ($Filename in Get-ChildItem $ImagePath)
{
$Arr = $Filename -split '_'
$reworkedfilename = $Arr[0] + '_' + $Arr[1] + '_' + $Arr[2] + '_' + $Arr[3] + '_' + $Arr[4] + '_' + $Arr[5]
##$reworkedarray2 = $Arr[0] -replace ".pdf", "";
Write-host $Arr[0] ##this works because I can see the non-primary ID being returned

#Find Each SPRIDEN_ID translated from CAID
add-type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient
$username = "U"
$password = "P"
$data_source = "DS"
$connection_string = "User Id=$username;Password=$password;Data Source=$data_source"
$statement = "
Select Distinct SPRIDEN_ID
from SARACMT, SPRIDEN
where 
SPRIDEN_PIDM = SARACMT_PIDM
and SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
AND SARACMT_COMMENT_TEXT = '$Arr[0]'
"
##The "AND SARACMT_COMMENT_TEXT = '$Arr[0]'" doesn't work because nothing is being returned in the index file

try{
    $con = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connection_string)

    $con.Open()
    $cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText = $statement
    $result = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
   
   # Do something with the results...
   $ArrConverted = while ($result.Read()) {
                    $result.GetString(0)
                    }
} catch {
    Write-Error (“Database Exception: {0}`n{1}” -f `
        $con.ConnectionString, $_.Exception.ToString())
} finally{
    if ($con.State -eq ‘Open’) { $con.close() }
}

$outputline =  $ArrConverted + '|' + $Arr[4] + '|' + $DocType + '|@@'+ $ImagePath + $reworkedfilename | out-file -filepath $IndexFilePath -Encoding "ascii" -append

#>
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your problem, because no loop example. 
Please see at OracleDataAdapter example, maybe it should help you for at least SELECT queries to iteract through. 
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDataAdapterClass.htm

Comment: My comment about a "loop" was not intended to mean that I knew what I was talking about. 

what I basically want to do is for every data element parsed out of the foreach filename, I want to feed into a sql query and save the result as a replacement for the first data element in the index file.

The sql works just fine. It just doesn't "cycle" through each parsed data returned by the foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is to do with how you’re trying to inject variable values into your sql query string:

```
$statement = "
Select Distinct SPRIDEN_ID
from SARACMT, SPRIDEN
where 
SPRIDEN_PIDM = SARACMT_PIDM
and SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
AND SARACMT_COMMENT_TEXT = '$Arr[0]'
"
```

If you add a `write-host $statement` after this line you’ll see it’s replacing just the `$Arr` part and *not* the `$Arr[0]` part, so your query contains something like:

```
Select Distinct SPRIDEN_ID
from SARACMT, SPRIDEN
where 
SPRIDEN_PIDM = SARACMT_PIDM
and SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
AND SARACMT_COMMENT_TEXT = '25643245 AjaWar Prav 2 FT 20200701[0]'
```

instead of:

```
Select Distinct SPRIDEN_ID
from SARACMT, SPRIDEN
where 
SPRIDEN_PIDM = SARACMT_PIDM
and SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
AND SARACMT_COMMENT_TEXT = '25643245’
```

To get it to replace the value of `$Arr[0]` you can surround it with `$( ... )` to use “command substitution” (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7#command-substitution) so your query becomes:

```
$statement = "
Select Distinct SPRIDEN_ID
from SARACMT, SPRIDEN
where 
SPRIDEN_PIDM = SARACMT_PIDM
and SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
AND SARACMT_COMMENT_TEXT = '$($Arr[0])’
```

Having said that, you’d be much better off using a parameterised query rather than building a dynamic sql string (see [Oracle Parameterized query in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811897/oracle-parameterized-query-in-c-sharp)) because as your code stands it’s vulnerable to a sql injection attack if you come across a deliberately mischievous file name (e.g. `‘ or 1='1_AjaWar_Prav_2_FT_20200701.pdf`).

See https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/what-is-sql-injection-and-how-to-stop-it for more about sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Just by sheer luck I figured it out.

I created a variable for $Arr[0]

$Arr0 = $Arr[0]

Then put the new variable in the where clause of where clause of the sql statement:

AND SARACMT_COMMENT_TEXT = '$Arr0'

This ran the query on each item parsed out during the foreach.