# change conditions inside WHERE clause depending on the values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this WHERE clause inside my sql query:

```
WHERE ta.year = 2023 and (0=25 or dep1.code = 25) and (0=0 or d.code = 0) and (0=0 or sg.group_code = 0) and (0=0 or sf.code = 0)
```

So I need to change one of the conditions depending on the parameters I get. Its *(0=25 or dep1.code = 25)*

If the request accepts parameters 25, 30 or 50, I need to use *(0=25 or dep1.code = 25)*
else *(0=10 or a.branch= 10)*

Its like i need something like this:

```
If (parameter == 25) 
{
where clause = (0=25 or dep1.code = 25)
}
else where clause = (0=10 or a.branch= 10)
```

I need the solution inside sql query because im using birt

Comment: What purpose have those conditions that are always false? Like `0=25`? And why do you want to use `OR`? This can be simplified to `25 IN (a.branch,...)`

Comment: @JonasMetzler: Assuming that the value is parametrized you get `(0 = @p1 OR dep1.code = @p1)`. I.e., if no code has been entered (`@p1 = 0`), the condition is TRUE. So basically the `dep1.code ` is ignored. This helps making the query dynamic.

Comment: You  need to use a parametrized query. See; [Oracle Parameterized query in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41811897/880990) (we don't know which language you are using in the front-end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` and `OR`:

```sql
WHERE (   parameter = 25
      AND (0 = 25 OR dep1.code = 25))
OR    (   (parameter != 25 OR parameter IS NULL)
      AND (0 = 10 OR a.branch = 10))
```

However, `0 = 25` and `0 = 10` will never be true so you can simplify it to:

```sql
WHERE (   parameter = 25
      AND dep1.code = 25)
OR    (   (parameter != 25 OR parameter IS NULL)
      AND a.branch = 10)
```

---

Which for your entire `WHERE` clause would be:

```sql
WHERE ta.year = 2023
AND   (  (   parameter = 25
         AND (0 = 25 OR dep1.code = 25))
      OR (   (parameter != 25 OR parameter IS NULL)
         AND (0 = 10 OR a.branch = 10))
      )
AND   (0=0 OR d.code = 0)
AND   (0=0 OR sg.group_code = 0)
AND   (0=0 OR sf.code = 0)
```

Which can be simplified to:

```sql
WHERE ta.year = 2023
AND   (  (   parameter = 25
         AND dep1.code = 25)
      OR (   (parameter != 25 OR parameter IS NULL)
         AND a.branch = 10)
      )
```

Comment: There is a reason for `0 = 25`. This is the result of the parametrized version `(0 = :p1 OR dep1.code = :p1)` with `:p1 = 25`. Since the first therm is false, `dep1.code` must match the parameter. But if the user does not enter a dep code, then  `:p1 = 0` and the first term is true, which means that the value of `dep1.code` does not matter. This is a way to automatically make only the columns matter for which a filter value is available without having to change the query itself.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes There is a reason for `0 = :p1` and if the OP had put that into their code then we would have accepted it at face value because it is a typical structure. There is not an obvious reason for `0 = 25` because the optimiser will optimise it away. If you are going to use variables in the code then just put the variables into the question; don't put the value into the question as it will just lead to confusion like this.